# Subscription working fine initially, but not returning any values when page refreshed on Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

When I navigate to a page in my Angular app, I am displaying data as expected using the below methods:

```
conversationsSub: Subscription;
usersSub: Subscription;
conversation: Conversation;
loadedMessages: Message[];

ionViewWillEnter() {
this.conversationsService.fetchConversation(this.conversationId).subscribe();
}

loadMsg() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
    this.conversationId = paramMap.get('conversationId');
      this.conversationsSub = this.conversationsService
        .getConversation(paramMap.get('conversationId'))
        .subscribe(conversation => {
          console.log('Conversation values: ', this.conversation);
    });
  }

ionViewWillEnter() {  
    this.loadMsg();
}
```

Here is some Conversations.Service code, I can provide more if required:

```
private _conversations = new ReplaySubject<Conversation[]>(1);

get conversations() {
    return this._conversations.asObservable();
}

 getConversation(id: string) {
    return this.conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(conversations => {
        return { ...conversations.find(conversation => conversation.id === id) };
      }));
  }

fetchConversation(id: String) {
    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: ConversationData }>('myUrl/conversations.json')
      .pipe(map(resData => {
        const conversations = [];
        for (const key in resData) {
          if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            conversations.push(
              new Conversation(
                key,
                resData[key].userId,
                resData[key].mechanicId,
                resData[key].messages
              ));
          }
        }
        console.log('Service Conversation ', { ...conversations.find(conversation => conversation.id === id) });
        return { ...conversations.find(conversation => conversation.id === id) };
      }),
        tap(conversations => {
          this._conversations.next(conversations); // not sure what this should do or does
        })
      );
  }
```

However, when I refresh the page, here is what's happening:

1. No data is displaying on the page
2. `console.log('Conversation values: ', this.conversation);` is empty
3. I also get this console error `this.conversation.messages is not iterable`

The above error is in relation to `this.loadedMessages = [...this.conversation.messages];` inside my `loadMsg()`

Can someone please tell me why this is fine when I first navigate to the page, but is causing issues when I reload?

Comment: since it works when you navigate but doesn't when you reload, I think the problem is the paramMap from the route which seems to be pushing something different (empty/ undefined). When you reload, is the url param still there in the url? You can check it by adding a tap and logging it: this.route.paramMap.pipe(tap(console.log)).subscribe(...)

Comment: I logged the paramMap in `loadMsg()` & the correct value is logged. It's appearing in the URL also even on reload.

Comment: what is `this.conversations` in your service adn how is it loaded. problem is it seems to contain something different when reloading vs navigating

Comment: Hi @bryan60 Thanks for looking at this. I've updated my question with some more service code. Please let me know if more is required, or I need to explain something

Comment: what is calling `fetchConversations`? is it being called in the reload case?

Comment: `fetchConversations` is being called on a different page that displays a list of conversations. What I require from this page above is to display a list of `Messages` within a specific `Conversation`. I did try to use it on this page also, but that didn't work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems

1. `fetchConversations` doesn't seem like it's ever being called if it's called by the list pages, and those list pages aren't loaded on a direct message navigation. You need to call it somewhere in the loaded page for it to run.
2. once you fix that, you're just getting the initial empty array value from your BehaviorSubject instead of the fetched value as your component is subscribing before the fetch finishes, use a ReplaySubject instead:

   `private _conversations = new ReplaySubject<Conversation[]>(1);`

replay subjects are like behavior subjects in that they cache a number of values and emit to new subscribers, but they don't have an initial value and won't emit till they have a value to cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I use `fetchConversations` here, or should I try to create a new `fetchConversation` method that uses the paramMap value?

Comment: depends on the needs of your app

Comment: I've added a `fetchConversation` method to my answer above, & updated `_conversations`. Also updated `ionViewWIllEnter` but the messages still aren't dispaying

Comment: you've messed up all the timing now and looks like you've broken the type. if you're just fetching the conversation on entry, jsut use the fetch method. or stick with the fetch all method